# Скульптор, ваятель

Tags: этимология

И второй мой вопрос из этой же серии.
Есть вид изобразительного искусства - скульптура. И, соответственно, тот, кто делает скульптуры, - скульптор.
Но есть еще слово "ваятель", которое сейчас чаще употребляется с несколько высокопарным оттенком. Но если, как было сказано выше, скульптор делает скульптуры, то что делает ваятель? По идее, изваяния. Но изваянием можно назвать не только скульптуру, но любое сооружение.
В общем, помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Слово "изваяние" произошло от "ваять", про которое читаем у Фасмера:

> > По Брандту (РФВ 25, 38), связано с вити (см. вить), подобно тому как напаяти "поить" связано с пити. Соответственно этому развитие знач. шло от "вить, лепить из глины" к "высекать из камня"; ср. др.-инд. vāyas "ткач", váyati "ткет", "плетет", которые связываются с вить; см. также Преобр. 1, 68. Этимология ненадежная.

То есть слово "ваять" имеет изначально "скульптурный" уклон, пусть версия и признана ненадёжной Фасмером, так что сооружение назвать изванияем можно лишь в переносном смысле.

Answer (score 2):

> > Но изваянием можно назвать не только скульптуру, но любое сооружение.

Вовсе нет. Ну, то есть назвать-то можно, просто никто и никогда не называет, например, Кёльнский собор изваянием.

Answer (score 0):

Традиционно ваяние подразумевает работу художника по природному материалу, чаще камню, реже дереву, представляющему массив, и в таком случае он — скульптор-ваятель, рубящий и режущий. Можно ваять не только скульптуры, а и штучные архитектурные детали зданий, пьедесталов, колонн: капители, порталы, наличники, орнаменты, медальоны.

Материалы, придуманные для формования и литья, позволили скульптору заниматься лепкой (мягкой) модели и доработкой отливки. Тут он — не ваятель в полном смысле слова, и тогда, когда имеет дело с листовым металлом, пластиком или комбинацией материалов.

Answer (score -1):

Вообще-то sculp - нож, царапать скоблить, резать,  точнее русское скалывать и скала в латыни идет от scul. Наше скула с далеко идущими корнями - скулить и школа, шкала, СКОЛОТЫ. Веток гораздо больше. Вернулось? Скальпель. Скульптор, шкала ну уж явно в латыни не родное.  Нет у них этимологии! И у немцев нет. Зато СКОЛОТЫ есть. Вся латынь - от этруссков-русских, от немцев,  потом испанцев, франков. Произведение ЦЕРКОВНЫХ позднейших средних веков, не иначе. Что ни слово - корешки русские, от гороха Pisum, до меча - gladius - гладкий.
ваять -связано с выемкой,  выей, вынимать, отнимать  и тд. воевать, выть и словом вы.

Фасмерам не понять русской ментальности, и тем, что в генах язык лежит, ассоциативный, смысловой, ими не вычисляемый.

Answer (score -1):

Всё проще.
По древне угорски ИЗ_ВАЙять.
ИЗ- камень (есть в коми-зырянском)
ВАЙ- давать

ИЗ_ВАЙяние - дословно КАМНЕМ ДАННОЕ.

Языки народов ЕВРАЗИИ развиваются с востока на запад. От Алтая-гималаев до Британи.

Comment: Вы серьезно думаете, что совершенно русское слова с русским крнем и приставной могло быть заимствовано из неведомого науке "древнеугорского" ?

Answer (score -3):

Возможно, связано с корнем  "ва" -- вода и тем самым  ять, буквой означающей твердое произношение в конце слов. Может, она когда и произносилась? А может, это просто твердая вода-лед?  Скульптура, как где-то слышал, берут камень и отсекают все лишнее. Долговечно, но долго, со льдом быстро.